# Cant clone git repo on MacBook Air

Tags: git, git-clone

I recently tried to clone git repo using html from GitHub. But it showed me the following error whenever I typed in git-related command lines in terminal (git clone url).

`xcrun: error: unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): could not use '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' because it is not a compatible arch).`

I tried looking it up and tried a few suggestions. I tried `install Xcode -select` but it did not work. Any help or suggestions is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can try removing the command line tools (`sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`) and reinstall them afterwards. It looks like you don't have *libxcrun.dylib* with the required architecture. You can confirm this by comparing the output of `file /usr/bin/git` and `file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib`.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! I uninstalled ine command line tools and it worked.

Comment: I just wrote my comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try removing the command line tools and reinstalling them afterwards:

```sh
sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install  # or in the GUI
```

It looks like you don't have *libxcrun.dylib* with the required architecture. You can confirm this by comparing the output of the following to commands:

```sh
file /usr/bin/git
file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib
```